# Recursively source files under a folder except *.bak

Tags: vimrc

As title howto source all files under a folder recursively except files that end with `.bak`

Comment: This would be simpler if that directory was part of runtimepath and followed conventions. Then you could use `runtime` with a glob

Comment: Given that the folder is in `runtime` what would glob would be to achieve the goal? @D.BenKnoble

Comment: for example if they were all in dir, you would use `runtime dir/*.vim dir/**/*.vim` i think. (Though if you use dir=plugin, and you get that setup before vim loads plugins, it will happen automatically.)

Answer (score 2):

Setting [wildignore](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'wildignore') can have quite a  few side effects (especially if done globally).

So I would do:

```
let s:prefix = '/path/to/folder'

let files = filter(glob(prefix . '/**/*.bak', 1, 1), "fnamemodify(v:val, ':e') != 'bak'")

for fname in files
    execute 'source' fname
endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only 'source' a file at a time. Therefore, build the list of files first, and then source them one by one.

```
set wildignore=*.bak
let s:prefix = '/path/to/folder'

for s:fname in glob(s:prefix . '/**', 0, 1)
    execute 'source' s:fname
endfor
```

However, normally you should only source *.vim files, so then it becomes

```
let s:prefix = '/path/to/folder'

for s:fname in glob(s:prefix . '/**/*.vim', 1, 1)
    execute 'source' s:fname
endfor
```

But note that file system search does not guarantee order, so there can be some side-effects.